# redraw datatable after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm having a datatable with filters. I use Ajax every 10 seconds to fetch new data and add new rows to the table. (table data are dynamic in the same page not by ajax)

```
$(function () {
    setInterval(checkNew,1000*10);

    $( "#orderdate" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '2013:2050',
        dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy",
        showAnim:"fold"
    });

    var table = $('#data').DataTable({
        "lengthMenu": [[-1], ["All"]],
        "bSort": false,
        "paging":   false,
    });

    $("#status").change(function() { table.column(4).search($(this).val()).draw() });

});

function checkNew(){
    $.post('getdata.php',{max: $("#lastid").text().trim() }).done(function (data) {
        if( data.trim() !== '' ) {
            $("table#data").prepend(data.trim());
            //need to draw datatable to filter and search new data added to the table
        }
    });
}
```

As you see i'm trying to update or draw the table with new data so I can filter or search them. If i search for new data it won't be displayed because it wasn't loaded with the DOM. But I can't redraw the table I've tried

```
$("table#data").DataTable().draw(); // new rows are added but can't be searched or filtered
```

And

```
$('table#data').dataTable().fnDraw(); //new rows are not added
```

So how to edit the code in anyway to correctly draw the table to filter and search new added data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatables provides [built-in functionality for handling loading data from an ajax request](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) into a table. Additionally, it provides a [reload](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) method that will refresh the data in the table.

In your case, you should be able to do something like:

```
var table = $('#data').DataTable( {
    ajax: "getdata.php"
});
```

and then:

```
setInterval( function () {
    table.ajax.reload();
}, 10000 );
```

There are additional options you may want to pass in as arguments to the reload function depending on your use case. I hope this helps!

Comment: in getdata.php and inside the lopp that gets rows   
    $myrows[] = "<tr role='row'>
                <td>".$row['orderid']."</td>
                <td>".$row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name']."</td>
                <td>".date('d-m-Y',$row['unix_time'])."</td>
                <td>".$row['final_total']."</td>
                <td>".$row['name']."</td>
            </tr>";
        }
        echo json_encode($myrows);

in index i get this error 'invalid json response'

Comment: [update]
in the loop: $arr[] = $row; to fetch the whole row of information but I need to select some specific data just 4 fields and still get the same error
"select orders.id as orderid,orders.unix_time,orders.final_total,orders.user_id,orders.auto_cancel,users.id as userid, users.first_name, users.last_name, 
payment_methods_translation.payment_method_id, payment_methods_translation.name from orders,users,payment_methods_translation where orders.id='$id' and orders.user_id = 
users.id and orders.payment_method_id = payment_methods_translation.payment_method_id and orders.auto_cancel='1'"

Comment: [update] i'm changing my code correctly but in the network tab of console i find this ajax "mydomain.com//getdata.php?_=1476648685734" not "mydomain.com//getdata.php?_=1476648685734" which means the ajax url is not correct i don't know why it's been changed that's why i get error (domain is https)

Comment: updated please review. Now i get json data but the table doesn't display anything it just says 'loading'

Comment: @PHPUser Please do not change your question after you get an answer. If you have a new question, ask a new question.